# Attribute routing on one method breaks convention routing to other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Given an ASP.NET Web API controller with two methods:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Put(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Both are reached as expected via convention based routing when hit with `/api/products/123` using PUT and DELETE methods respectively.

If I then add an attribute route to the Put method to make it:

```
[Route("api/products/{id}"]
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id)
```

then as expected the Put method continues to respond to PUT requests on the same path, however the DELETE request is no longer routed to the delete method, receiving instead a 405 Method Not Allowed reponse. Adding the same route attribute to Delete gets things working again.

I'm trying to understand why this is happening, and whether using attribute routing on one method means I always need to use it on all the others too.